# How can I remove duplicates and add a new unique file?

Tags: php, file, random, download, unique

I have on my website to grab 5 random files from all the files in my directory and all is going well but about %50 of the time I get a duplicate.  I would like to:
1) Remove duplicate
2) Replace with new unique file

.. or maybe I can prevent duplicates in an easier manner all together? I tried to find a function for this without asking a question of here but I have not found one. Any ideas? Thanks!!

```
 <?php 
 //define stuff
$dir = "uploads/";
$allfiles = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..'));
echo '<pre>';
print_r("all files ready for access");
echo '<pre>';

// create zip
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = "zipfile.zip";
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){
    $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}
else {
    echo '<pre>';
    print("created zip");
    echo '<pre>';
}

// array of random files    
$n=1;
while ($n<=6){
    $n ++;
    $file = array_rand($allfiles);
    $randomfile = $allfiles[$file];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($randomfile);
    echo '<pre>';
if (file_exists($dir.$randomfile)) {
    $content = $dir.$randomfile;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($content);
    echo '<pre>';
    $zip->addfile($content,$randomfile);
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
}

//present for download
$zip->close();
ob_get_clean();
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($zip_name) . ";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_name));
    readfile($zip_name);
  if(file_exists($zip_name))
{
  unlink('zipfile.zip');
}

?>
```

Comment: You could create an array with all file entries, then randomise that array using ``shuffle()`` and then pick the first 5 items in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if you already found this file. And if you already found it, get a new one by continuing without incrementing `$n`.

Look at this:

```
// array of random files    
$n = 1;
$myfiles = [];
while ($n<=6){
    $file = array_rand($allfiles);
    $randomfile = $allfiles[$file];
    if(!in_array($randomfile, $myfiles)) { // this line checks if you already got this file
        $myfiles[] = $randomfile;
    } else {
        continue; // if you already got it, continue (http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.continue.php)
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($randomfile);
    echo '<pre>';
    if (file_exists($dir.$randomfile)) {
        $content = $dir.$randomfile;
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($content);
        echo '<pre>';
        $zip->addfile($content,$randomfile);
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
    $n++; // increment in the end
}
```

Comment: wow thanks!! this works perfectly.  had to switch $myfiles and $randomfile because the function wants the array second :P but damn thats perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a second parameter to the `array_rand`function:

```
$my_files = array_rand($allfiles, 5);
```

or shuffle the array and get -for example- the first five items:

```
shuffle($allfiles);
// now $allfiles[0...4] are 5 different files.
```

Answer (score 0):

create a an array for the files already added to the zip :

```
$added = //array
$zip->addfile($content,$randomfile);
array_push($added,$randomfile)
```

and check any new file in the above array before inserting:

```
if(!in_array($randomfile, $added)){
  //add the file to zip
}
```